# Execute script retrieved as a string

Tags: javascript

I need to find the most correct way to display and execute an advertising banner inside a div with this format:

```
<div id="1111-1"><script src="//ads.website.com/s/gen.js?type=2"></script><script src="//ads.website.com/s/requestform.js?siteId=1111&formatId=2"></script></div>
```

I have prepared a div with:

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid"></div>
```

but I can't execute anything. I've tried:

```
 let element = document.getElementById('adsmoneytizer').innerHTML = app.forum.attribute('adscode') || "";
    eval(element);
```

where app.forum.attribute return the string `"<div id="1111-1"><script src="//ads.website.com/s/gen.js?type=2"></script><script src="//ads.website.com/s/requestform.js?siteId=1111&formatId=2"></script></div>"`

How can I display and execute this code?

Answer (score 0):

You should be appending `element` to the body for the script to execute:

```js
let element = document.createElement('div')
element.innerHTML = app.forum.attribute('adscode') || "";
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Comment: i get TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node

Comment: tried to put <div id="example">
    <script>
        alert("Welcome");
    </script>
</div> as a code but not work

Comment: @juniorDevFla Sorry again. Try my code again. It now creates a new `div` element.

Comment: does not work unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

you should use eval() instead to make it works

```
 $(this.node).find('script').each(function(index, element) {
        eval(element.innerHTML);
```